# Select RANDOM row from 60k rows fast with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database 60k rows, 4 columns (ID,Keyword,Status,Updet ) and try to select rand fast using this :

```
SELECT Keyword 
FROM keyword AS r1 
JOIN (
    SELECT CEIL(RAND() *(SELECT MAX(id) FROM keyword)) AS id
) AS r2 
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 1
```

but the problem is i can't select the row with conditions Updet='published', and have try

```
SELECT Keyword 
FROM keyword AS r1 
JOIN (
    SELECT CEIL(RAND() *(SELECT MAX(id) FROM keyword)
) AS id) AS r2 ON r1.id >= r2.id 
WHERE Updet='published' 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 1
```

not working, please help..

Comment: I'm not an expert on MySql, but can't you just use `ORDER BY RAND()`?

Comment: the result will slow respond and overhead for sorting each row

Comment: i can't understand it, can you explain it to me?